# Before Trigger on Lead Conversion doesn't appear to be firing in Test Method

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, lead-conversion, before-trigger

I am writing a test to test lead conversion. The test is failing because the lead has a failing lead validation rule that checks a custom field value that is set using a Before trigger. However, even though we have the `Enforce Validations and Triggers` setting turned on, during the test, the Before trigger doesn't appear to be firing.

Here's the relevant bits of the test code:

```
// convert the lead with signed status
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(l.id);
LeadStatus convertStatus = [select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted = true limit 1];
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

// assert the lead was converted
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
```

In the trigger, I placed this line to see what's going on. During a normal run the output works. During the test, it doesn't fire at all.

```
System.debug('Lead Trigger: ' + Trigger.operationType);
```

There's only one trigger for Lead and the first line is the debug statement. The trigger just isn't getting fired for some reason.

Does anyone know if a Before triggers should fire whilst testing the lead conversion process?

Is there anything I need to set before executing the conversion process?

Comment: Do you have any trigger handler framewok? You then need to insert a record to enable triggers. https://www.salesforce.org/table-driven-trigger-management-matters/

Comment: No, there's currently no trigger framework in this org. Also updated the question with more detail.

Comment: assuming you actually have an `insert l;` statement in your testmethod, then the only reason I can see for before triggers not to fire is `When the request comes from other sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call, Salesforce validates only the foreign keys. Before executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself.`

Comment: @cropredy the error occurs when the convert process tries to update the lead status, but the new status causes a validation failure on another field. If `before update` was firing, the validation error wouldn't occur since the `before update` trigger sets the appropriate value.

Comment: ok -- I know you said there is no trigger framework but do you have recursion control? Inserting a lead in a testmethod and then converting it will occur in the _same_ transaction and any static variables will not be cleared between the original mocking of the test lead and the execution of the `convertLead`. (In the UI, these two events are in _separate_ transactions

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there was code that abruptly ended the execution of the trigger because of a missing `Custom Setting` in the test context.

After removing this code, the trigger executed as expected.